# difficulty understanding these pronouns

Tags: pronouns

Who are you/he/she in your/his/her highness or in your/his/her excellency?

Who are these people? I mean "her majesty" is the queen. But who is her?

One more example is "his holiness". "His holiness" is Dalai Lama. But who is his?

Comment: One addresses the queen as “your majesty,” but speaks about her as “her majesty.”

Comment: _Her_ is the possessive, not another person.

Comment: *I [would ask **your good self***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22would+ask+your+good+self%22) to consider these examples from Google Books (which typically  *don't* involve a particularly exalted royal or ecclesiastical addressee).

Comment: The full (subscription-only) OED includes [this observation](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/112614#eid38660624) regarding the use of the possessive in such contexts: *Honorific forms of address such as **Your Majesty** (cf. also **excellency** n., **grace** n., **highness** n., **lordship** n.) generally agree grammatically with **3rd-person verbs** but **2nd-person pronouns**: see quots. 1761, c1777. **This is not the case in French, German, etc.***

Comment: It's merely a title. Or, if you prefer, merely an idiom. Don't think too much into it. Now it is sunny in my area. What is ***it***? The answer, nobody knows and nobody will ever know. Most words lack any real referent in the world.

Answer (score 0):

The addition of a pronoun is to make this term a title.  "Her" highness, Queen Anne, could not be shortened to, "Highness, Queen Anne."    Highness, by itself simply means elevated or revered.  It does not refer to a specific person, and does not operate as a title.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, I though this was a forum where non-native speakers asked native English speakers for help with grammar, syntax, and the like.  I did not know the answers needed to be 'documented,' as if they were then going to be used in a term paper.   There seem to be too many rules, so I will just pass on through.  Thank you.

Comment: @Patrick But notice that the comment is from a bot, probably programmed to add this comment to all answers lacking a link. I dislike this bot and ignore it. You should too.